# Onesignal Android SDK Error

Tags: android, onesignal

I've tried to implement Onesignal into my android project , but Im having this error about Firebase :

> Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.1

I did everything in the documentation : https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup#section-android-studio

Here is my build.gradle

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:[0.9.0, 0.99.99]'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.package"
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                onesignal_app_id: 'XXXXXX-1b8c-48d3-a596-d277fad80edc',
                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                onesignal_google_project_number: 'XXX921710280' ]
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 2
        versionName "v2.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.simbiose:Encryption:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.scottyab:aescrypt:0.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.bloder:magic:1.1'
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.9.1'
}
```

Comment: Use classpath google play services version 3.3.1, Firebase 15+ is supported by it.

Answer (score 0):

In **build.gradle** :

Add :

```
jcenter()
```

In your `repositories`

Then Sync `Gradle`  Again .

Comment: I don't have any mavenCentral in the file

Comment: @ChaoukiAnass what's your **android studio** version ?

Comment: my version is 3.1.2

Comment: @ChaoukiAnass did you Check `Global Gradle sestting` to unckeck `Offline work` in your **android studio** ?

Comment: @ChaoukiAnass Of course , go `File>Settings>Build,Execution,Deployment>Build Tools>Gradle` find `Offline work` checkbox , and if it was checked , uncheck it . Then **Sync Gradle** again

Comment: I've found the solution , check my comment

Answer (score -1):

It works now , I had to implement the same version for :

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
```